# Google Sheets onEdit no triggering with copy & paste

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

i've the following script it is working perfect when I enter on my own numbers.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if(col === 4 && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() ===  "Inventur"  ){
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,8).setValue(new Date());
    
  }
}
```

Now when I copy & paste a text in there, the timestamp will not change.
My question is, how I can get this one working also with copy & paste?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Add an screenshot to the script executions page. Also add more details (like the name of source and destinations sheets as well the reference of the source and destination ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will update the timestamp as long as e.range.columnStart==4 and e.range.rowStart>1.

If you want it to do something different then you will have to change it.  What is it that you wish it to do?

Animation:

[image]